# como puedo obtener el parametro de entrada de mi funcion decoradora

Tags: python, class, parametros, decoradores

la funcion interna recibe por defecto el parametro de la funcion que esta decorando, en este caso seria self, me gustaria replicar @property decorador de python para poder ejecutar funciones como variables pero cuando trato de ejecutar la funcion interna del decorador este tiene un parametro el cual no puedo obtener de ningun modo ya que para poder obtener si o si la funcion interna debe ejecutarse la cual no puedo ejecutar por que me falta el parametro self del la Clase Persona alguna ayuda.

```
class refclass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ref = 0

    def add(self, args):
        self.ref = args

    def ret(self):
        return self.ref




def propiedad(params_func):

    obtener = refclass()#clase que obtiene la referencia de objeto de Persona

    def obtener(self):
        return self

    def interno(self):
        nonlocal obtener
        obtener.add(self)
        return params_func(self)

    #return interno(lambda self: obteners(self)) o return interno(lambda self:self) no funciona
    #trate de capturar self con un metodo anonimo pero no me funciona, de esta forma me gustaria 
     ejecutar obj.getNombre como si fuera variable.
    # en caso de retornar return interno() da error de que falta el argumento self el cual no 
     puedo obtener. 


    #return interno 
     #de esta forma puede ejecutarse pero obj.getNombre() se ejecuta como metodo y no como 
     variable


class Persona:

    def __init__(self, nombre, edad):
        self.__nombre = nombre
        self.__edad = edad

    @propiedad
    def getNombre(self):
        return self.__nombre

    def setNombre(self, nombre):
        self.__nombre = nombre

    def getEdad(self):
        return self.__edad

    def setEdad(self, edad):
        self.__edad = edad


carmen = Persona('carmen', 27)


print(carmen.getNombre)
```

gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿por qué no usas el @property de python? Tratar de re-implementarlo tú mismo es complejo y hay que conocer bien el modelo de datos Python. Y eso que sólo estás intentando hacer el getter. La implementación del setter se complica aún más.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es más complicado de lo que pretendes. El decorador simplemente cambia una función por otra, pero al final el resultado hay que llamarlo también. Es decir, cuando haces:

```
@propiedad
def getNombre(self): return self.__nombre
```

en el fondo has hecho:

```
def getNombre(self): return self.__nombre
getNombre = propiedad(getNombre)
```

Con lo que cuando se invoque `getNombre()` se invocará la función que haya sido retornada por `propiedad`, pero en todo caso **debe ser invocada**. ¿Cómo hace entonces el `@property` de Python para permitir que mágicamente al acceder a esa propiedad?

Ocurre que la función retornada por ese decorador es en este caso una clase que implementa el patrón *descriptor* que consiste en implementar, entre otras, una función llamada `__get__()`.

### Descriptores

Un descriptor es un objeto que implementa `__get__()` (y otros métodos en los que no entraré por no complicar la respuesta).

Python trata de forma especial a los atributos que son descriptores. Si tú tienes un `objetoX` que es instancia de una cierta `ClaseX` e intentas acceder a `objetoX.propiedadX` Python intentará lo siguiente:

- Buscará `propiedadX` en `objetoX.__dict__` que es un diccionario en el que están todas las propiedades y funciones de `objetoX`
- Si lo encuentra ahí, mirará de qué tipo es el `valor` que contiene esa propiedad. Es decir `valor = objetoX.__dict__["propiedadX"]`

  - Si ese `valor` es otro objeto que implementa `__get__()` (es decir, es un *descriptor*) invocará `valor.__get__(objetoX, ClaseX)` y devolverá lo que esta función devuelva.
  - Si no, devolverá simplemente `valor`
- Si no lo encuentra aún intentará `objetoX.__getattr__("propiedadX")`, pero esto no es relevante en esta pregunta.

Por tanto para emular el decorador `@property` debes implementar una clase que:

- En su constructor reciba una función (que será el método de la `ClaseX` que quieres decorar y convertir en propiedad)
- Implemente un método llamado `__get__()` (para convertirse así en un *descriptor*). Este método recibirá como parámetro un `objeto` sobre el cual se está intentando acceder a  una propiedad. Desde aquí habrá que invocar a la función que se recibió en el constructor y se le pasará como parámetro el `objeto` (para que así ese método lo reciba en `self`).

Es decir:

```
class propiedad:
    "Emulacion muy limitada de @property"

    def __init__(self, funcion):
        self.funcion= funcion

    def __get__(self, objeto, clase=None):
        return self.funcion(objeto)
```

Demostración de funcionamiento:

```
class Cosa:
  def __init__(self):
    self._foo = 200

  @propiedad
  def foo(self):
    return self._foo

c = Cosa()
print(c.foo)
```

Resultado: `200`.

### Como funciona el ejemplo anterior

Al poner `@propiedad` delante de `def foo`, ocurre que:

- Se define la función `foo` "normalmente"
- A continuación se hace `foo = propiedad(foo)`

Como consecuencia de esto último se invoca al constructor de la clase `propiedad`, pasándole `foo` como parámetro. Ese constructor guarda entonces `foo` en la variable `funcion` y retorna.

Después instanciamos la clase `Cosa`, mediante `c = Cosa()`

Cuando se intenta acceder a `c.foo` ocurrirá el siguiente proceso:

- Python mira en `c.__dict__` a ver si hay ahí el símbolo `"foo"`
- Efectivamente lo encuentra, y su valor ahora mismo es una instancia de la clase `propiedad`, pues ya hemos visto que al decorar `foo` hemos cambiado su valor por el valor retornado por `propiedad(foo)`.
- Python mira a ver si existe `foo.__get__` y encuentra que sí, por lo que `foo` implementa el protocolo *descriptor*, y Python realiza la invocación `foo.__get__(c, Cosa)`
- Dentro de ese `__get__()` se invoca a `self.funcion` que según vimos apunta a la antigua versión de `foo`. Así que cuando se ejecute `self.funcion(objeto)` se acabará llamando a la antigua versión (antes de decorarla) de `foo()` pasándole `c` como parámetro. Este parámetro lo recibirá en `self`.
- Cuando la función `foo()` original se invoque de este modo, retornará `self._foo` que en este momento es `c._foo` y por tanto accedemos al valor 200.

### Retorcido, eh?

Y aún habría que contar cómo se implementaría un setter, que es más complicado aún pues una vez se ha definido `@propiedad` sobre el método `foo`, debería ser posible después usar `@foo.setter` delante de otro método, lo que significa que nuestra clase `propiedad` debe definir el método `setter()` que tome la función que sigue y la devuelva decorada (para lo que la guardaría e implementaría `__set__()` para poder llamarla luego, de forma similar a como hicimos con el getter).

Como ves todo es muy farragoso. Me pregunto por qué reinventar la rueda y no usar directamente el decorador `@property` que ya te da Python,  y que además es más eficiente pues tiene todas estas cosas implementadas en C.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta se te agradece mucho, quise reinventar la rueda para poder entender como funciona en profundidad, crear mi propio decorador que haga lo mismo solo por aprender, bueno algún libro, pagina o algún curso que me podrías sugerir que tenga que ver con clases,decoradores,métodos mágicos e instancias de clases,manejo de archivos, entre otras cosas y con lo que me acabas de aclarar te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Una buena referencia que a menudo pasamos por alto es la propia documentación de Python. Es exhaustiva y allí está todo, y es la última palabra en caso de dudas. Es verdad que es tan grande que puede ser difícil saber por dónde comenzar. Pero para este tipo de cosas "avanzadas" te recomiendo leer la sección sobre [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). Respecto al asunto concreto de los descriptores, tienes también una sección: [Implementing descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors).

Comment: Aparte de la documentación estándar, un libro muy bueno que particularmente me gustó mucho y tiene un equilibrio perfecto entre la explicación del lenguaje y los detalles avanzados de cómo funciona, es "Fluent Python" de Luciano Ramalho